# Mocking Issue: Working Locally but Failing in CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, github-actions, fastapi

API done in FAST API
I'm getting the error: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' in the pipeline but it shouldn't because I'm mocking the connection with magic mock. The tests work perfectly in my local machine.

This is my main.py

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from typing import Annotated
from data.database import engine,SessionLocal
from data.models import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session 
from routers import contacts, users

app = FastAPI()
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db=SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

db_dependency=Annotated[Session,Depends(get_db)]
# Configure CORS to allow requests from your Angular frontend


origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.include_router(contacts.router, prefix="/contacts", tags=["Contacts"])
app.include_router(users.router, prefix="/users", tags=["Users"])

@app.get("/health" ,tags=['Health'])
async def check_health():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

conftest:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import pytest 
from main import app
from routers.contacts import get_db


mock_session=MagicMock()

def override_get_db():
    try:
        yield mock_session
    finally:
        pass

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] =  override_get_db

@pytest.fixture
def mock_db_session():
    return mock_session
```

My tests:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from data.models import Contact
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from routers.contacts import get_db
from main import app


client = TestClient(app)


def test_create_contact(mock_db_session):
    url="/contacts"
    contact={"first_name":"Giovanni",
             "last_name":"Rossi",
             "email":"giovanni@gmail.com",
             "phone_number":"1234567890" ,
             "user_id":1
             }

    response = client.post(url, json=contact)

    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()
    assert data["first_name"] == "Giovanni"
    assert data["last_name"] == "Rossi"
    assert data["phone_number"] == "1234567890"
    assert data["email"] == "giovanni@gmail.com"


    mock_db_session.add.assert_called_once()
    mock_db_session.commit.assert_called_once()
    mock_db_session.refresh.assert_called_once()

def test_create_without_user_id(mock_db_session):
    url="/contacts"
    contact={"first_name":"Giovanni",
             "last_name":"Rossi",
             "email":"giovanni@gmail.com",
             "phone_number":"1234567890" ,
             }

    response = client.post(url, json=contact)
    assert response.status_code == 422

def test_create_without_phone_number(mock_db_session):
    url="/contacts"
    contact={"first_name":"Giovanni",
             "last_name":"Rossi",
             "email":"giovanni@gmail.com",
             "user_id":1
             }

    response = client.post(url, json=contact)
    assert response.status_code == 422

def test_get_contacts(mock_db_session):

    mock_query = MagicMock()
    mock_query.filter.return_value.all.return_value = [
    {
        "last_name": "Rossi",
        "id": 68,
        "phone_number": "1234567890",
        "email": "giovanni@gmail.com",
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "Giovanni"
    }
    ]

    mock_db_session.query.return_value = mock_query

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda:mock_db_session
    response = client.get("/contacts/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == [
    {
        "last_name": "Rossi",
        "id": 68,
        "phone_number": "1234567890",
        "email": "giovanni@gmail.com",
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "Giovanni"
    }
    ]

def test_get_empty_contacts(mock_db_session):

    mock_query = MagicMock()
    mock_query.filter.return_value.all.return_value = []

    mock_db_session.query.return_value = mock_query

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda:mock_db_session
    response = client.get("/contacts/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == []
```

platform darwin -- Python 3.10.9, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
plugins: anyio-3.7.1

The error: ImportError while loading conftest '/home/runner/work/gitworkflow2/gitworkflow2/backend/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:3: in 
from main import app
main.py:11: in 
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Comment: The problem was this line of code: Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine). The mocking was working perfectly. The thing is that in the configuration, that creates all your models in the db. So, that should only be run manually . I modified to be a function for now and it worked perfectly in my pipeline.